# Comma or no comma in "Overlooking the entire coastal village(,) was a small mountain"?

Tags: grammar, commas

> Overlooking the entire coastal village, was a small mountain.
>
> Overlooking the entire coastal village was a small mountain.

Do you need to put a comma here after village or is it completely wrong to put a comma here? Considering you can move the subject around and say "A small mountain was overlooking the entire coastal village", I am thinking it's ok to put a comma, but I am not sure.

Comment: What do you think? Do you think that a pause is required at that point?

Comment: The comma is definitely not required. I'm curious about whether it's permitted at all. The comma doesn't separate the subject and main verb, so it seems it should be OK, but it feels odd to me to put a comma before the main verb regardless of the sentence structure. Interesting question.

Comment: @gotube the comma is emphatically **not** permitted; inserting it creates a comma splice.

Comment: @randomhead A comma splice separates two independent clauses. There is only one independent clause in that sentence. "Overlooking the entire coastal village" has no subject and no verb with tense, so it's not a clause.

Comment: @gotube good point, I misspoke. It would be a [yob's comma.](https://info.cooley.edu/blog/round-up-those-stray-commas-says-wmu-cooleys-otto-stockmeyer)

Comment: @randomhead I'm not arguing that the comma is right or wrong, but a non-academic book calling people "stupid" and "illiterate" for using one before any verb doesn't make it incorrect. It would be more helpful to reference authoritative sources, like reputable style guides, grammar reference books, etc.